# What are the rules to be followed while doing push ups at home

Tags: push-ups

Lately, I have started doing push ups at home. I have started this a year ago, paused and resumed it recently. In-order to maintain and keep of track of it, I am using an Android application.

Having no knowledge of fitness rules to be followed when doing push ups, often I get confused  regarding the position when doing push ups.

What should be the distance between my two palms when put on the floor? How wide should I keep my foot? I believe, I am not following this as I am dong it at home. Also, I am not using any equipment. I am just making use of my flat floor. How can I correct this and do it properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Palms under your shoulders.

Back straight from your head to your heels. Don't sag or A-frame.

Feet together or shoulder width apart.

Touch the ground on every rep at the bottom. Extend elbows fully at the top.

Pack the shoulders and [crush the armpit trolls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKLvNCxNtwU).

Comment: Palms under shoulders is traditional push up form, but it really depends on what muscles the OP is trying to work out.

Comment: Wider between palms - more emphasis on the pecs.
Narrower between palms - more emphasis on the triceps.
A-framing - more emphasis on the upper part of the pecs (I suggest you do this as well sometimes, for variety since you are only doing pushups. Just targeting the same part of an as large muscle as the pectoralis can lead to unaesthetic results; by doing just regular straight push-ups you will hypertrophy the middle pectoral segment, and the end result will be a round, almost breast-like muscle when you flex).

Comment: I agree that push-up variations are possible, necessary in the long term, and perpetually awesome. Since the question is from someone who is likely a fitness noob, I focused on the basics. Both of your comments on variations would make good answers if fleshed out.